# videocall app getting stuck in certain point

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

while developing agora video call app the application is getting stuck on clicking call end button

- This is where I am getting the breakpoint

/// Function to dispose the RTC and RTM engine.

```
Future<void> endCall({required SessionController sessionController}) async {
      await sessionController.value.engine?.leaveChannel();
      if (sessionController.value.connectionData!.rtmEnabled)//This is where its getting breakpoint {
        await sessionController.value.agoraRtmChannel?.leave();
        await sessionController.value.agoraRtmClient?.logout();
      }
      await sessionController.value.engine?.destroy();
    }
```

The code is

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:agora_uikit/agora_uikit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart'; 
class VedioCall extends StatefulWidget {
  String channelName = "test";
  VedioCall({required this.channelName});
  @override
  State<VedioCall> createState() => _VedioCallState();
}

class _VedioCallState extends State<VedioCall> {
 late final AgoraClient _client;
  bool _loading = true;
  String tempToken = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    getToken();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getToken() async {
    String link =
        "https://Agora-Node-TokenServer.vinaym4.repl.co/access_token?channelName=${widget.channelName}";

    Response _response = await get(Uri.parse(link));
    Map data = jsonDecode(_response.body);
    setState(() {
      tempToken = data["token"];
    });
    _client = AgoraClient(
      agoraEventHandlers:  AgoraRtcEventHandlers(  
        leaveChannel: (State)=>Navigator.pop(context),
        
      ),
        agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
          appId: "5a4c1108a1af4a76924c9461d120dc47",
          tempToken: tempToken,
          channelName: widget.channelName,
        ),
        enabledPermission: [Permission.camera, Permission.microphone]);
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then(
      (value) => setState(() => _loading = false),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: _loading
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : Stack(
                children: [
                  AgoraVideoViewer(
                    client: _client,
                  ),
                  AgoraVideoButtons(client: _client)
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

in the debug console section

- E/flutter (28049): #0      endCall
- E/flutter (28049): #1      _AgoraVideoButtonsState._onCallEnd

Plz anyone help me to get rid of the failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that sessionController.value.connectionData is not null:

```
Future<void> endCall({required SessionController sessionController}) async {
      await sessionController.value.engine?.leaveChannel();
      if (sessionController.value.connectionData != null && sessionController.value.connectionData!.rtmEnabled) {
        await sessionController.value.agoraRtmChannel?.leave();
        await sessionController.value.agoraRtmClient?.logout();
      }
      await sessionController.value.engine?.destroy();
    }
```